# How to update the associated model in a transaction in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 table, Expert and Industry.  Every expert belongs to many industry， how to update them in a transcation?

I konw setter method could update the association without transcation, I need it perform more robust.

```js
Expert.belongstoMany(Industry,{through:"expert_industry"})


async function updateExpert(data) {
    const expert = await Expert.findByPk(data.id, {
        include: [
            {
                model: Industry,
                through: {
                    attributes: []
                }
            }
        ]
    })

    const industries = Industry.findAll({
        where: {
            id: data.industry_id
        }
    })

expert.setIndustry(industries)

// Here I want update expert and its industry in a transcation, How to do it ?
    return sequelize.transaction(t => {
// The sql to insert or delete table expert_industry doesn't appear in this transcation
// and I don't know which should be the owner of update function, Expert(model) or the expert(instance)?
        return Expert.update(data, {transaction: t})
    })

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambigous a bit, I'm not fully getting what you wanna do with `indusries` since it's not doing anything. But I get the update part.

I think you should querying twice, one is for updating Expert model and the other is for Industry.

Try this,

```js
return sequelize.transaction(t => {
    try{
       await Expert.update(data, { transaction: t })
       //you should add where option, otherwise your whole rows are gonne be updated
       
       await Industry.update(data, { transaction: t, where : { expertId : data.id } })
       //expertId  should be your foreign key
    }
    catch(e){
       throw e
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for reply.I want to update table `expert_industry`,I konw there is a methond `setIndustry` in my case could update  `expert_industry` automatically.But it's beyond transcation.  Am I clear? As aresult I readed its source code today, and I have found solution.

Comment: Would you do me a favor correct my description?

Answer (score 0):

The source code of belongstoMany are in `belongs-to-many.js`

> Set the associated models by passing an array of instances or their primary keys.
> Everything that it not in the passed array will be un-associated.
>
> @param {Model} sourceInstance source instance to associate new instances with
> @param {Model|Model[]|string[]|string|number[]|number} [newAssociatedObjects] A single instance or primary key, or a mixed array of persisted instances or primary keys
> @param {Object} [options] Options passed to `through.findAll`, `bulkCreate`, `update` and `destroy`
> @param {Object} [options.validate] Run validation for the join model
> @param {Object} [options.through] Additional attributes for the join table.
> set(sourceInstance, newAssociatedObjects, options)

So you could pass a transcation instance into this method.In my case it would be

```
Expert.belongstoMany(Industry,{through:"expert_industry"})


async function updateExpert(data) {
    const expert = await Expert.findByPk(data.id, {
        include: [
            {
                model: Industry,
                through: {
                    attributes: []
                }
            }
        ]
    })

    const industries = Industry.findAll({
        where: {
            id: data.industry_id
        }
    })



    return sequelize.transaction(t => {
        // You could pass transcation instance into the setter method
        expert.setIndustry(industries,{transcation:t})
        return Expert.update(data, {transaction: t})
    })

}
```